# How to turn off flick to scroll for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Still new to iOS developement. I had a question about customizing the scroll behavior of a `UIScrollView`. My scroll view currently bounces back if I don't flick the view. How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Set scrollView Bounces property to false , Through code **scrollView.bounces=false**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `scrollView.bounces = false`

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and the "snap back" behavior is still happening. Does this have anything to do with the scrollview being larger than it's superview? Or something of that nature.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to set isPagingEnabled to false.